# sublime 3 text and tab size for cpp files

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I have trying to set tab size to 2 and replace with spaces for all file types (including my *.cpp files).

In:
/home/user/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings

I have:

```
{
  "tab_size": 2,
  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

I have restarted sublime text but tabs are still 4 and tabs instead of spaces in my .cpp files.

Do I need to convert existing *.cpp files after I made this change?

UPDATE:

Apparently you have to do a **Select-all** go to **View -> Indentation** and select the indention size of choice on existing files for it to be applied.

Comment: I would not expect it to auto update the format of the code.  What happens if you select all, copy and then paste?

Comment: No effect. I just tried to create a new *.cpp file and then it work. For some reason it has no effect on files before I made the change. You have thought this would have been a rather basic feature - that existing files would be updated.

Comment: Your update should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

Apparently you have to do a **Select-all** go to **View -> Indentation** and select the indention size of choice on existing files for it to be applied.